# Can one get the RAM Utilization with python and/or Powershell, without Cache?

Tags: python, powershell, utilization

Is there a way to get the RAM Utilization with powershell/Python, without the cached ram?
We want to monitor the utilization of our System parameters. At the moment I use this in powershell, which gets calles by task scheduler every 30 minutes together with other parameter checks:

```
...
$counts = 6
$Samples = 145
for($j=0; $j -lt $counts; $j++){
    $temp = 0
    $result = 0
    for ($i=0; $i -lt $Samples; $i++){
        $os = Get-WMIObject Win32_OperatingSystem
        $os | select *memory*
        $pctUsed = [math]::Round(100-($os.FreePhysicalMemory/$os.TotalVisibleMemorySize)*100,2)
        $temp = $pctUsed + $temp
        Start-Sleep -s 2
    }
$result = $temp/$Samples
...
```

which will then be sent to a Monitoring application of us.

How can we get RAM without Cache? Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to do some work to get the raw data into MBs /GBs. Look into `Get-Counter -ListSet *memory* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Counter` to list all which will list all performance data property names you can use to get the info you need. Such as:
 `Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'`

Comment: I have mine set up for GPU monitoring that gets the information off my miners to let me know when one goes does

Comment: With the '''Get-Counter -ListSet *memory* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Counter''', I can only find '''GPU Memory''' and '''.NET Memory Cache''' for example.
I can't find ''' Memory\Available MBytes '''. Then I get the message, the object hasn't been found on the computer

Comment: Are you adding the wildcards?

Comment: Yes, I enter ```Get-Counter '\Memory\Available MBytes'```

Comment: `Get-Counter -ListSet *memory* | Select-Object -ExpandProperty  Counter` paste your results from this

Comment: Results are ```\GPU Local Adapter Memory(*)\Local Usage
\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Shared Usage
\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Dedicated Usage
\GPU Adapter Memory(*)\Total Committed
\GPU Process Memory(*)\Shared Usage
\GPU Process Memory(*)\Dedicated Usage
\GPU Process Memory(*)\Non Local Usage
\GPU Process Memory(*)\Local Usage
\GPU Process Memory(*)\Total Committed
\GPU Non Local Adapter Memory(*)\Non Local Usage
```

Comment: AND ```\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Hits
\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Misses
\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Hit Ratio
\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Trims
\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Entries
\.NET Memory Cache 4.0(*)\Cache Turnover Rate```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it checks the Ram usage in real time.

```
Function Check_RAM{
$time= Get-Date
$usedMemory = Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem
$totalMemory = $usedMemory.TotalVisibleMemorySize
$freeMemory = $usedMemory.FreePhysicalMemory
$usedMemoryPercentage = ($totalMemory - $freeMemory) / $totalMemory * 100
Write-Host "Used Memory Percentage $usedMemoryPercentage% at $time"
}
do{
Check_RAM
start-sleep -Seconds 10
}until($infinity)
```